# Connecting to Exchange office 365, Shared mail box

Tags: vb.net, office365, exchangewebservices

After we migrated all to office365, my application that reads mails sent to a certain shared mailbox has failed.

I am not sure how to fix this. It worked fine before migration.

At that time my credentials were:

> exchangeService.Credentials = New WebCredentials("User",
>   "PW", "windowsdomain")
>           exchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl("inboxxx@domain.com")

and I was using URI:
'

> exchangeService.Url = exchangeService.Url = New Uri("https://owa.DOMAIN.com/ews/exchange.asmx")

and exchangeservice Exchange2010_SP2.

However after migration it has not worked, even though I think I updated code correctly(apparently I haven't).

The code I have been trying is this: (This does not work)

```
Sub GetEmails()

    Dim exchangeService As New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013)
    'WebService Uri
    'Try
    exchangeService.Url = New Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx")



    exchangeService.Credentials = New WebCredentials("user@domain.com", "PW")
    exchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl("inboxxx@domain.com")


    Dim findResults As FindItemsResults(Of Item) = exchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, New ItemView(10))
    For Each item As Item In findResults.Items
        Dim strID As String
        'Get mail ID
        strID = item.Id.ToString
        'Get Lid from mail subject
        strLid2 = item.Subject.ToString
        strLid2 = UCase(strLid2.Substring(strLid2.Length - 8))
        'Get attachements
        Call GetAttachmentsFromEmail(exchangeService, strID)
        'Move email
        Call MoveEmail(exchangeService, strID)
        'Upload files to case
        Call GetFiles()

    Next

End Sub
```

I hope someone can help me, or point me in the right direction, so I can overcome this challenge.

Br
VG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the FolderId class to specify the Mailbox you want to access if its a shared mailbox eg

```
FolderId MailboxToAccess = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "SharedMailbox@domain.com");
exchangeService.FindItems(MailboxToAccess, New ItemView(10))
```

Get rid of the Autodiscover line it does nothing for you as all it will do is discover the URL of the CAS server (which is a single endpoint in Office365 which you have already specified statically). It has no baring on what mailbox your connecting to.

Comment: It still does not seem to work, I changed it to this: 
Dim findResults As FindItemsResults(Of Item) = exchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, "sharedmailbox@domain.com", New ItemView(10))
        For Each item As Item In findResults.Items
            Dim strID As String

Comment: But you haven't used the FolderId class what your using will always connect to the Mailbox of the security credentials

Comment: Thankyou Glen, it works like a charm now. I had to use folderId class just as you said.